# In android how to add Vertical ViewPager?

Tags: android

I have my MainActivity like

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Main layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);

    // SlidingMenu
    sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    sm.setBehindOffset(120);
    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);

    // Left menu
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new LeftMenuFragment()).commit();

    // Right menu
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_second);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new RightMenuFragment()).commit();

}
}
```

How can I create vertical pager in this activity? I want to also to scroll vertical between two layouts(fragments).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager), but it doesn't seems it is supported anymore

Comment: I try to use that library, but I have conflict with library[https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu]. They both use android-support-v4 library.

Comment: there is a fork, which fixes compatibility issue: https://github.com/keiththompson/Android-DirectionalViewPager/commit/6ef2b4a3a16616b3f190b26c8e194230852e342f

Comment: There is very good project for vertical naviagtion https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager